# Bootstrap JavaScript Is Not Working with WebPack

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am recently working on projects using **Webpack**, **JS** and **Bootstrap**, but suddenly on the project I am currently working on, and despite using the same Webpack and npm configs the bootstrap Javascript stopped working, although It shows in the javascript bundle in the Sources tab in the browser.

**Notes:**

- All my .js files and styles in the entry file i.e **index.js** work fine and all libraries, too.
- The order of imported files is:

  1. jquery
  2. popper.js
  3. bootstrap.min.js
- Using CDNs for both Jquery and Bootstrap instead of imports did not fix the problem.

Here is the code on GitHub: https://github.com/WeamAdel/webpack-template

**Webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
     main: "./src/index.js",
     home: "./src/assets/js/home.js",
  },

  output: {
   // filename: "assets/js/[name].[fullhash:7].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      //JS
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
        },
      },
   },

  // HTML
  {
    test: /\.html$/i,
    loader: "html-loader",
  },

  //Pug
  {
    test: /\.pug$/i,
    use: ["html-loader", "pug-html-loader"],
  },
   ],
 },

 plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.pug",
        chunks: ["main", "home"],
     }),
     new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],

  optimization: {
     minimize: true,
     minimizer: [
        `...`,
        new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
```

};

**index.js**

```
import "jquery";
import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min";
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the webpack code in question directly

Comment: @Pytth I have just added snippets from Webpack.confing.js and index.js

Comment: How has it "stopped working?" Are you getting errors? Is nothing happening? Does the page take longer to load? More details por favor :)

Comment: No errors and It does not take long to load. Dropdowns, Navbar collapses just does not do anything when I click them.

Comment: Can you please show the HTML that would hold the script tag(s) for the built package(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this topic finding a solution for the same symptoms.
In my case the problem was, I had bootstrap version 4.6.0 installed, but copied and paste code snippets for version 5.0.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I have been trying to fix it for 4 months now :'D, thank you so much, that really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install the (exact) version of bootstrap and add your classes accordingly.